# Dart: Invalid override

Tags: dart, overriding, subclass

The following code:

```
abstract class Foo {
  List<Object> get c;

  Foo update(List c);
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  final List<int> c;

  Bar(this.c);

  Bar update(List<int> l) => new Bar(l);
}
```

generates the message:

```
ERROR: Invalid override. The type of DA.update ((List<Date>) → DA) is not
       a subtype of Attribute.update ((List<dynamic>) → Attribute).
```

I'm using version 1.16.0-dev.5.1.

Is this correct?  I thought a subclass is a subtype.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in strong mode with generic type parameters

If you disable strong mode (bottom right) the error messages goes away

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a0b78c0b5ac01d6b700599d0f4f56085)

I think this is the issue to be followed https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26151

Comment: Thanks.  The issue 26151 you mentioned above, says that if you modify the code from dynamic to Object it works.  But my modified code above still generates the error in Strong mode.  So, my questions is: should this be an error in strong mode?

Comment: You are right. I tried that as well and also got that error. There is a lot of work going on related to checked-mode. Maybe the mentioned example is a bit different or it is some regression. If you think this case should have it's own bug feel free to report. If the Dart team members think otherwise they will close it as duplicate - no harm done.